# What plugin / 3rd-party software would you recommend to setup OBS to stream to Skype or sites such as Appear.in?

Tags: video, screen-recording, streaming, video-conferencing

## Setup

- Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
- 16GB RAM
- Intel Xeon CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz 2.53GHz (2 processors)

## Looking for

- Free / Open-Source software or plugin.

With a bit of Googling, I could only find tutorials on how to setup Skype as a video source into OBS ([Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)), but what about the other way around?

What I want to do is broadcast the stream **FROM** OBS to a website that has access to a Camera (such as Appear.in), or Skype. Currently, I have no way to "pick" the stream from OBS, because A) it would require OBS to output the stream to some custom adress / plugin, and B) Since it's a "stream" and it's not recognized as a "camera", most websites / apps don't list it in the available Cameras running on my system.

Is there any plugin or open-source solution that you would recommend that runs as a *Virtual Camera* on your system and can take a local stream (from OBS) as an input? (This is assuming I could just point OBS to some local IP address the plugin would be listening on).